# how to send searching criteria to server and showing searching result in another page?

Tags: gwt

very simple situation, one search page with several searching criteria, when user fill in and press 'search', the searching criteria is pass to server and retrieve database and put the result in a arrayList, then the server redirect the page to result page, showing the searching result.

I do not know how to do the final step, "show the result in result page"
if using GWT-RPC method, 
is we get the result arraylist in onsuccess method of callback object then jump to another page in onsuccess method?
but I do not know how to implement this, especially the part "send the result and jump to another page"

if I do this using PanelForm method, I also stuck on the step how the result (an arrayList) pass to the show result page? or how the show result page get the search result in server?

Answer (score 0):

sorry for my english,

you'll get the list in onsuccess method

```
public void onSuccess(List list) 
{                           
     List resultList = new ArrayList<com.shared.PanelFormVO>();
     for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
         PanelFormVO ld1 = (PanelFormVO) list.get(i);
         resultList.add(ld1);
     }
     cellTable.setRowData(resultList);  
}
```

this code will show you how to put the data in cell table..
else u can use the list to use the data